# Exception fault(Segmentation fault) creating a singly link list in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

Program to create a singly link list but an Exception error (Segmentation fault) occurs while printing the data stored in the link list, although the program runs and show output
.

```
//Program to create a singly link list
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
void main()
{
    struct node *head, *newnode, *temp;
    head = 0;
    int choice = 1;
    while (choice)
    {
        if(choice==1)
        {
        newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("Enter the data ");
        scanf("%d", &newnode->data);
        newnode->next;
        if (head == 0)
        {
            head = temp = newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = newnode; 
            temp = newnode;
        }
        printf("Do you want to continue - Press 1 to continue and 0 to terminate ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        }
    }
    temp = head;
    while (temp != 0)
    {
        printf("%d\t", temp->data);/*Here it show Exception error(Segmentation fault)*/
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to step through, most of the times it gives immensely valuable info about the issue at hand.

Comment: `newnode->next;` as a statement doesn't do anything.  Did you intend something to actually happen here, maybe `newnode->next = 0;`?  Otherwise I don't think your list ends up null terminated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in this statement

```
newnode->next;
```

It seems you mean

```
newnode->next = NULL;
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```